# Python creates directories and files in a different place than specified

Tags: python, windows, directory, path

When I try to make two directories like so:

```py
import os
os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getenv('APPDATA'), 'folder 1'))
os.mkdir('C:\\Users\\ivan\\AppData\\Roaming\\folder 2')
```

the folders get created in `C:\Users\ivan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\Roaming`
and there are no folders created in the directory specified in the code. It is the same story with creating files.

Googling "python creates directories and files in a different place then specified" or "python changes path before saving file" didn't give me any good results.

I tried looking in the documentation of the function in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5950e7dbfcd9307c7e74184a1586ef99f9f35c3b/Modules/clinic/posixmodule.c.h#L2279y), but I couldn't find the body of the function `os_mkdir_impl`(seems to be internally implemented).

When reading files or folders on the other hand you seem to have access to both places and if they overlap, say you have:

1. `C:\Users\ivan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\Roaming\file.txt`
2. `C:\Users\ivan\AppData\Roaming\file.txt`

It will open the first file

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that `'C:\\Users\\ivan\\AppData\\Roaming\\folder 2'` doesn't get created? Do you get an error message, or it silently fails?

Comment: It does get created in ```C:\Users\ivan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\Roaming```. The problem is it should be created in ```C:\Users\ivan\AppData\Roaming```, but it's not. No error messages appear.

Comment: Thanks, I see. I can't replicate this - it works fine for me, but I'm using Miniconda, so not the same way of installing Python as you, so it's not really a direct comparison.

Comment: You might want to *print(os.getenv('APPDATA'))* Also, (bearing in mind that I despise Windows) I seem to recall that the Roaming directories have some weird properties. Try creating folders elsewhere. If *mkdir()* fails it will, without doubt, raise an exception

Comment: This is also the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76014099/209989

Answer (score 1):

Found [the answer on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/12b0ckc/pythonwindows_10_writing_files_to_appdata/). Essentially, the problem is that you've installed Python from the Microsoft App Store and it's getting sandboxed. Uninstall it and reinstall from python.org.